# Angular Check Date is valid in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, date

Can you tell me how to check the validation of a Date in Angular?
I used const date = new Date(2018, 02, 29), it just created this wrong date without any verification!
Then i have found a piece of code:

```
const date = new Date(year, month-1, day);
if((date.getFullYear()===year) && (date.getMonth()===month+1) && (date.getDate()===day) {return true;}
return false;
```

But it doesn't work for Angular!
Do you have any ideas, please?
Thanks.

Comment: how was the date wrong? can you please clarify? `new Date(2018, 02, 29)` will create a date with the date of 29th march 2018

Comment: Maybe because you are passing `month-1` and checking for `month`

Comment: @xyz its probably to take into account the fact that months are 0 indexed

Comment: @mast3rd3mon so for month "2" the user is passing as `2 - 1 i.e: 1` for this "getMonth()" will give `0` and now the comparison is `0 === 1 + 1`

Comment: @xyz no, get month will still return 1, it doesnt return month -1. however, the op code should be `date.getMonth()+1===month` or `date.getMonth()===month-1`

Comment: @mast3rd3mon: I understand now!

Comment: new Date(2018, 02, 29) or new Date(2018, 02, 30) don't exist, it should be a wrong date